# ERROR: syntax error at or near "NEW" Position: 179

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers, plpgsql

object: public.fn_set_now_as_updated_at | type: FUNCTION --
-- DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS public.fn_set_now_as_updated_at() CASCADE;

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.fn_set_now_as_updated_at ()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    VOLATILE 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    SECURITY INVOKER
    PARALLEL UNSAFE
    COST 1
    AS $$
NEW.updated_at = NOW();
RETURN NEW;

$$;
```

Comment: That syntax has little to do with PL/pgSQL, so the error is not surprising. I suggest that you have a look at the manual.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you forgot to add **begin** an **end** clause [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.fn_set_now_as_updated_at ()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    VOLATILE 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    SECURITY INVOKER
    PARALLEL UNSAFE
    COST 1
    AS $$

    BEGIN
        NEW.updated_at = NOW();
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$;
```